# CMS/framework for research / scientific analysis

Tags: content-management-system

I'm going to be starting a few projects and papers soon with 3 others, and I'd like some central web-based tool that we can collaborate (and publish, blog-like) on our research.
I've thought about using something simple like wordpress, but that doesn't really add much richness to the information.

A few things that we might need are:

- *blog posts* (publicly visible),
- Project/experiment *journal* (logged-in only) where we could document *raw data*, perhaps tabulated,
- MAYBE *graphing* this data, that would be cool,
- uploading *files*, with notes on them (*photos*, for example),
- Usable by both *technical* users (who might want to annotate or write about sourcecode) and *non-technical* users.
- A *timeline* of activity on the site, so we would know what each other are working on,
- Preferably not something I would need to host myself

Does anyone know of a cms/whatever that would we could use that would serve this purpose?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a wiki is more in line what you are looking for.  Not sure about hosting but I have used hosting providers in the past that install applications for you, maybe worth looking around.

Comment: A wiki would definitely be part of my solution, but a wiki is just simple pages of rich text. What I want is a little more structure.

Comment: Have a look at Umbraco, it is completely customisable and has a lot of plugins.

Comment: Eh..  .net? I'm not so sure :-/ However, I've gone with your original suggestion of a wiki, it's good enough and doesn't get in the way.

Comment: To be honest a wiki sounds like a better solution, it will cost less to set up and any decent wiki lets you set up content templates that gives you a standard approach to creating content.